# (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)) allocating more then one char?

Tags: c

I am having some trouble understanding how memory is allocated to `sir[i]`. From what I understand `(char*)malloc(sizeof(char))` should only allocate space for one character, but when I run the code it can read any word, regardless of length. Can someone plese explain how/why does this happen?

```
void read(char **sir,int **ln,int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Read word %d: ",i+1);
        sir[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s",sir[i]);
        ln[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
        *(ln[i])=strlen(sir[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: fflush(stdin) invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Thats undefined behavior.

Comment: I'm getting tired of linking the dups for this:(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Answer (score 3):

You write beyond the boundary of the memory you allocated. This is undefined behavior, and you are unlucky enough that it seemed to "work".

Answer (score 1):

It's called a buffer overflow resulting in undefined behavior. It may or may not crash your problem, but it is a security hole nonetheless.

`scanf` with `%s` without a maximum length specified is always a security hole just like `gets()` and should not be used!

BTW: `sizeof char` is guaranteed to be `1` so you don't need to specify it - just use the number of chars you need; multiplying by `sizeof char` is likely to be optimized away by your compiler.

Comment: Isn't the security risk is when the buffer is on the current stack frame?

Comment: @StoryTeller Nope. It also a security risk per-se.

Comment: @FUZxxl, I'm not familiar with any attacks that work with memory allocated on the heap. But if you have a reference I'd be happy to learn something new.

Comment: @StoryTeller *I'm not familiar with any attacks that work with memory allocated on the heap.*  Corrupting the heap is a DOS attack at least.  And given knowledge of what's in the heap and where, arbitrary data could be used to overwrite something important.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_overflow mentions one

Comment: @AndrewHenle Lookup Heart Bleed for a fatal heap overflow attack.

Comment: @FUZxxl Thanks.  I knew there were examples, but it's too early in the morning so I was just pointing out in general terms how overflowing a heap buffer could be an attack vector.

Answer (score 0):

> From what I understand (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)) should only
>   allocate space for one character

Thats correct. `malloc` in this case returns a pointer to 1 byte of allocated memory.

```
fflush(stdin);
```

Is undefined. At this point, anything may happen.

```
scanf("%s",sir[i]);
```

Is also undefined. Again, at this point anything may happen, from crashing your program with a segfault to it seemingly working.